# Is there a way to keep the application switcher active on the screen all time?

Tags: 11.10, unity, application-switcher

I like the way it works. I like the way it looks. It could be more better If i can keep the application switcher on screen all time, not only when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and switch apps using mouse click on it.

Is there a way to do it in a safe way? I don't want to use Compiz Settings Wizard. Is there a way doing it using Dconf Editor? I feel it more safer.

```
Heres the Image what I was indicating:
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay ! here what I have done. There's a alternative to what I have asked, that is "GLX Dock". You can use that.

By setting its appearance to transparent and using right theme you can achieve a second launcher at any where on your desktop.

Look at the buttom of my desktop. That is what I'm talking. You can install "GlX dock" from Ubuntu Software Center. Go there and install it.

Under settings menu you can find the option to place it any where on the desktop. You can do it by setting the "Position" and the "margin" value.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible. You can switch your applications easily by pressing the icon on the launcher to the left. Isn't an application switcher annoying which appears permanently in front of all windows?

Comment: Yes it will be! Actually I thought I would stick it to the screen ans set it "keep below". But seems no way to do that, So....

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 12.04

1. Startup System Settings
2. Click Appearance
3. Click the tab Behavior
4. Slide the bar for "Auto-hide Launcher" to OFF

Comment: Im on Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric. Not Ubuntu 12.04